# Using filter on angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to filter to just one store, given the store Id, which is picked in a dropdown.

HTML:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="store in orderVm.Stores | filter :{store.id=orderVm.Stores.selectedStore.id}">
```

I don't get how to set up the filter so that it only shows the one store with the specified id.

controller:

```
vm.Stores = json;// from file
vm.Stores.selectedStore = { 
    id: vm.Stores[0].Id, 
    name: vm.Stores[0].MarketplaceName 
};
```

vm.Stores:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "MarketplaceId": 1,
    "MarketplaceName": "Etsy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "MarketplaceId": 2,
    "MarketplaceName": "Shopify"
  }
]
```

The error I get is unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=32&p3=orderVm.Stores%20%7CNaNilter%20%3A%7Bstore.id%3DorderVm.Stores.selectedStore.id%7D&p4=.id%3DorderVm.Stores.selectedStore.id%7D

Comment: you shouldn't refer to an iterator in your filter, so try:  {Id=orderVm.Stores.selectedStore.id}

And note that it's case sensitive.

Comment: filter's first paramter accepts either a `string`, `object` or `function`, so syntactically it should be `{Id: orderVm.Stores.selectedStore.id}` instead, note the equals sign and the colon

Comment: This worked: filter: {Id:orderVm.selectedStore.id} but I don't know why. Specifically, I don't know why Id must be capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple to filter your data by value:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="store in orderVm.Stores | filter:Vm.Stores.selectedStore.id">
```

It will get objects with properties have value is `Vm.Stores.selectedStore.id`. Because name not is a number (id), you can use this filter for it.

To specific filter by value of id:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="store in orderVm.Stores | filter:{Id:Vm.Stores.selectedStore.id}:true">
```

**Syntax**: `filter:{propertyName:value}:true`

`true` is for exact match.

Comment: I tried this:
filter:orderVm.Stores.selectedStore.id but it does not filter - it give me all stores. At least I don;t get an error.

Comment: OK, this one worked: filter:{Id:orderVm.Stores.selectedStore.id}:true

Comment: I don't understand why I'm using Id when I have specified id Is Id reserved by the filter or repeater?